# excel 2007 VBA Subscript out of range, ReDim Preserve issue when no duplicates found

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code below to identify duplicates in a column and delete ALL duplicates if found.  I have the exact same code in another workbook and it's working fine.  However, I am receiving "Subscript out of range" error when I compile code below.  The highlight is on "m = UBound(toDel2) to LBound(toDel2) Step -1.  I have looked online for help, and have been trouble shooting for hours.  Could someone provide assistance?

```
    Dim toDel2(), m As Long
    Dim RNG2 As Range, Cell2 As Long
    Set RNG2 = Range("a1:a1000") 'set your range here

    For Cell2 = 1 To RNG2.Cells.Count
        If Application.CountIf(RNG2, RNG2(Cell2)) > 1 Then
            ReDim Preserve toDel2(m)
            toDel2(m) = RNG2(Cell2).Address
            m = m + 1
        End If
    Next
    For m = UBound(toDel2) To LBound(toDel2) Step -1
        Range(toDel2(m)).EntireRow.Delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs when no duplicates are found causing toDel2 to be empty so you are unable to get the UBound or LBound.

This will fix the issue for you:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim toDel2(), m As Long
    Dim RNG2 As Range, Cell2 As Long
    Set RNG2 = Range("A1:A1000")    'set your range here

    For Cell2 = 1 To RNG2.Cells.Count
        If Application.CountIf(RNG2, RNG2(Cell2)) > 1 Then
            ReDim Preserve toDel2(m)
            toDel2(m) = RNG2(Cell2).Address
            m = m + 1
        End If
    Next

    On Error GoTo NO_DUPLICATES
    For m = UBound(toDel2) To LBound(toDel2) Step -1
        Range(toDel2(m)).EntireRow.Delete
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

NO_DUPLICATES:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You would get the error you mention on the line you mention if it turns out that there are no rows to delete, because in that case `toDel2` won't ever have been redimmed.  My guess is that that is what's happening, because your `m` variable would cause a problem if `toDel()` was redimmed, so that can't have ever happened.  Given that `m` will be zero to start with, you should have the `m=m+1` before the `ReDim`

Comment: @KazJaw perhaps you misunderstood what I wrote?  Your answer mentions exactly the point that I made 10 minutes earlier!

Comment: `Dim m` is enough to make `Redim` working (by default `m=0` and it's not necessary to increment it by 1 before `Redim`).

Comment: @KazJaw I think that unless `m=m+1` is before the `Redim`, the line `toDel2(m) = RNG2(Cell2).Address` will cause a `Subscript out of range` error if there are rows to delete.  But at least we agree on what's actually causing the problem :-).

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem:

```
ReDim Preserve toDel2(m)
```

You are not setting `m` to anything before this line so it is still 0.  When you use this format of `ReDim`, you are telling it to allocate `m` or zero items in the array.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this statement:

```
if Application.CountIf(RNG2, RNG2(Cell2)) > 1 Then
```

never returns `True` therefore your `toDel2 array` is never fully declared. `Subscript out of range` says in your situation that array is empty, it was not successfully Redim'med.